Generate PDF from a template
I need to generate PDF from an ASP.NET Core project, and I need to import a template then fill the existing field.
My question is: how can I create a PDF and fill it after in the code?
Is there is any software can make a PDF as template?
I'm using:

iTextSharp
Illustrator


you can use a visual tool to create very simple templates (Acroforms, for instance), and then use tools like iText to fill in these simple fields, and turn them into "regular" PDFs.. I kind of like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0j8VrsXt1o, but I am biased.

Multiple solutions, even MS Word can be used. https://www.textcontrol.com/blog/2024/04/05/generating-ms-word-docx-and-pdf-documents-with-asp-net-core-c-sharp/
In my project, some methods of iTextSharp turned invalid, choose the tools suitable for your project structure.

While there are multiple programs available to create PDF documents I would suggest Adobe InDesign for the task. Since you are using Adobe Illustrator already it should not be difficult to learn the skills needed to create form templates with text fields, radio buttons, etc., and export as PDF. Indesign will give you the greatest degree of control over your document design, far more than most other programs. You then would use iText to marry data from some data source such as a web form or database table to the form. I’ve done this hundreds of times. There are some intricacies you will need to tackle when working with iText to write data to a PDF template but it’s absolutely achievable and my suggested path.
